# adding custom parameter to install-package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, nuget

I am building a nuget package which uses an install.ps1 script in the tools folder. I want to pass parameters into this install script in the install-package command.

So running in package manger inside visual studio

install-package mypackage -myparam param

param would then be passed into the install.ps1 file inside the tools folder.

Is this possible? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK that's not possible. The Install-Package cmdlet exposes a few options which map to properties on the [InstallPackageCommand](http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/09e6046d6eaf#src/VsConsole/PowerShellCmdlets/InstallPackageCommand.cs) in the NuGet sources. You could maybe log an issue or submit a pull request for this kind of functionality?

Instead of trying to extend the Install-Package cmdlet, why not create your own cmdlets and expose that one after installation (similar to MVC scaffolding package)?